# Test code with Exceptions and with no exceptions at same time (JAVA)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng, mockito

I am writing a test for already built java class function. I am writing tests using Testng and Mockito and have a Data Provider.

This is my Test

```
@Test(dataProvider = "myProvider", dataProviderClass = StaticDataProvider.class,
        expectedExceptions = SomeException.class)

public void myControllerTest(String argument) throws Exception {
    // Mocked object bussiness\
    Boolean resultantObject = business.getList(argument);
    Assert.assertTrue(resultantObject);
}
```

This is my Controller which I want to test

```
public Boolean controller(String argument) {
    if(argument != null) {
        throw new someException();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sucess");
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my Data Providor

```
@DataProvider(name = "myProvider")
public static Object[][] getDirectoryList() throws Exception {
    Object[][] result = null;
    // case1 throws SomeException
    String testData1 = null;
    // case2 don't throw exception
    String testData2 = "String";
    result = new Object[][] { { testData1 }, { testData2 } };
    return result;
}
```

The problem here I am facing is, I don't want to create another test just to test both buggy and non buggy code and complete my test coverage using a single test case. But when I put Expected Exception on top, it fails on correct code, and when I dont, it fails on buggy code.

NOTE: This is example code and may not work, this is just to take an idea of scenario I am working on and what I am expecting.

Comment: Different expectations: different test cases.

Comment: Isn't there any way that I can accomplish this in one go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you ignore the "*one test, one assertion*" purist perspective, I think most people agree you should split tests that involve error conditions from tests that prove normal behaviour.

If you want to test multiple error conditions within one test (or if you're really keen on continuing with your plan), you can use this pattern:

```
try {
  // something that should cause an exception
  fail("Exception expected");
} catch (ExactlyTheRightException e) {
  // ignored
}
```